# FreeBSD Process and Thread Control Block

Tags: freebsd

I need an overview of what data is kept in FreeBSD 9.3's Process Control Block and in it's Thread Control Block. Where can I find that information?

Answer (score 1):

In system headers; in the FreeBSD source tree it's sys/sys/proc.h, search for "struct thread" and "struct proc".

You might also want to consult the "Design and Implementation of the FreeBSD Operating System" book.